# Is software developed in UK is patentable in US?

Tags: patentability, patent-applications

I work for a company in UK. This company is a branch of an american company. We have developed a software that resolves technical problems in an innovative way for the processing payments industry. I know software is not (generally) patentable in UK. The question is: can we  file a patent for our software in US? The software has been developed in UK entirely.

Comment: After the SCOTUS decisions of the past few years, patent protection for software implemented inventions might even be easier in the UK. I know a U.S. firm that sometimes filed first in the UK and then uses a program called PPH to fast track into the USPTO with success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where an invention is created has no impact at all on the ability to be patented in the US. Nor does the nationality of the inventor or company. Under the [Paris Convention](https://www.wipo.int/edocs/pubdocs/en/intproperty/611/wipo_pub_611.pdf), all (177) member countries must give people and companies from all other member countries the same substantial patent rights as they give their own nationals.

> ARTICLE 2, paragraph
>   (l) Nationals of any country of the Union shall, as regards the
>   protection of industrial property, enjoy in all the other countries of
>   the Union the advantages that their respective laws now grant,
>   or may hereafter grant, to nationals ; all without prejudice to the rights
>   specially provided for by this Convention. Consequently, they
>   shall have the same protection as the latter, and the same legal remedy
>   against any infringement of their rights, provided that the conditions
>   and formalities imposed upon nationals are complied with.

In most places software based inventions are difficult to patent - sometimes impossible. It’s very complicated and a moving target at least in the US. I would suggest you consult with an experienced patent attorney/agent to determine the issues regarding the patentability of your invention in the US, the UK and elsewhere.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I would welcome a more authoritative answer. Or else feel free to edit mine.